# UILongPressGestureRecognizer works on simulator but never on the device

Tags: ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer

I have this snippet of code in the viewDidLoad of my ViewController

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer* gestureRecognizer = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(_handleLongPress:)];
gestureRecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
gestureRecognizer.minimumPressDuration = 5.0;
gestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];
NSLog(@"Gesture recognizers = %@",self.view.gestureRecognizers);
```

and the methods

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {
    return YES;
}

- (void) _handleLongPress:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
     if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
         NSLog(@"Started");
}
```

When I run this app and click on the view for 5 seconds the `_handleLongPress` gets trigger, however when I run the same app on the device it never hits the `_handleLongPress` method.. what am I missing? I do see the output that there is the long press :

`2014-08-01 10:00:48.505 TestConsole[1343:60b] Gesture recognizers = (
    "UILongPressGestureRecognizer: 0x14644d30; state = Possible; view = UIView 0x1453f950>; target= <(action= _handleLongPress:, target=MyViewController 0x1463a730>)>"`

I put breakpoints at `gestureRecognizer:shouldReceiveTouch:` and it does hit that the UILongPressGestureRecognizer.. I am dumbfounded!

Comment: Make sure the addGestureRecognizer line is actually getting executed when running on the device.

Comment: Yes it does. updated code above.

Comment: `_handleLongPress` is not called at all? I mean, if you put an `NSLog`/breakpoint before the state check, does it print?

Comment: Nope it does not print or hit the breakpoint.